# Как стать специалистом по информационной безопасности?

Tags: безопасность, информатика

**Здравствуйте!** Я очень интересуюсь темой информационной безопасности, но не знаю с чего начать изучение. Подскажите пожалуйста, с чего начать свой путь белового "хакера"?

**P.S.** Может быть, есть какие учебные пособия, книги, и т.п?

**Заранее спасибо!**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. тебе необходимо понимание низкоуровневой (нулей и еденичек) работы компьютера, для этого тебе нужна математика
2. тебе нужно знать распостранённые стандарты (типа rfc-all all заменить на цифры), для этого тебе нужно знание английского
3. тебе нужен выход в сеть tor, ибо там пишут что-либо более-менее рабочее